# pony.orm sort by newest Entity in relationship

Tags: python, ponyorm

Let's say i have these tables mapped with `pony.orm`:

```
class Category(db.Entity):
    threads = Set("Thread")

class Thread(db.Entity):
    category = Required("Category")
    posts = Set("Post")

class Post(db.Entity):
    thread = Required("Thread")
    timestamp = Required(datetime)
```

Now I want to get all threads of a certain category ordered by there newest post:

With this line I get the **ID** of the newest post, but I want the object.

```
query = select((max(p.id), p.thread) for p in Post if p.thread.category.id == SOME_ID)
    .order_by(lambda post_id, thread: -post_id)
```

Of course I could `[(Post[i], thread) for i, thread in query]` or `select(p for p in Post if p.id in [i for i,_ in query])`

But this creates additional sql statements. So my question is: How can I get the newest posts of all threads in a certain category sorted by the timestamp of that post with a single sql statement.

I wouldn't using `db.execute(sql)` if you can't use the ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select((p, t) for t in Thread for p in t.posts
              if p.id == max(p2.id for p2 in t.posts)
       ).order_by(lambda p, t: desc(p.id))
```

Comment: Wow, that's why I love pony.orm: It's just python. But what I don't understand: why is `select(t for t in category.threads)` invalid -> "iterating over non-entity object" but `select(p for t in Thread for p in t.posts)` fine? In both cases I am iterating over a `Set` relationship.

Comment: `select(t for t in category.threads)` should be fine too, but the corresponding translation logic is not implemented yet. It should be relatively simple to do, but other tasks were more urgent. Hope we can implement it soon.

Comment: Isn't `max(p2.id for p2 in t.posts)` the same as `max(t.posts.id)`?